# How to sort second index of multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Not sure if titled the question correctly but first of all

What kind of array is this?
Second how do I sort the second index by ASC or DESC

**For example where it says float(....
How do I sort that?**

Been trying to use rsort and arsort but just not getting the results I need.

If I have code like this

```
array(24) { 
           [0]=> array(2) 
           { [0]=> string(4) "AAPL" [1]=> float(64.756994020789) }

           [1]=> array(2) 
           { [0]=> string(3) "AMD" [1]=> float(57.268267955388) }

           [2]=> array(2) 
           { [0]=> string(4) "BABA" [1]=> float(57.24625652504) } 

           [3]=> array(2) 
           { [0]=> string(4) "BIDU" [1]=> float(65.24289909913) }

           [4]=> array(2) 
           { [0]=> string(5) "BRK.B" [1]=> float(52.178207183616) }

           [5]=> array(2) 
           { [0]=> string(3) "CAT" [1]=> float(50.412401981782) }

           [6]=> array(2) 
           { [0]=> string(3) "DIA" [1]=> float(55.683323570131) }

           [7]=> array(2) 
           { [0]=> string(3) "DIS" [1]=> float(47.435360931467) }

           } 

           rsort($array);
           var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Okay, I think I understood the question. Where is your attempt?

Comment: I was just using a rsort() function or the arsort() function but it kept just sorting the string

Comment: How about `usort()` with a comparator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `usort` with your custom sorting function:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) { return $a[1] - $b[1]; });
// as of php7
usort($array, function($a, $b) { return $a[1] <=> $b[1]; });
```

Comment: Not sure how that really worked but it worked. I had to go w3schools to see the basic example of usort. They provided a function but i replaced that with your function return syntax and it worked perfectly. It sorting from ASC. Not sure why the $a and $b where passed to the function since it doesnt look like im passing anything to the function.

Comment: The (lambda) function is simply a comparator. `uasort()` is calling that function iternally do determine, which value is bigger, so you don't have to provide the two values `$a` and `$b` yourself.